# How to check if a file exists into s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm moving my site to Amazon S3 and Cloudfront, since these are all public resources I suppose to enable s3 website hosting.
But I would like to understand what's best (and cheaper) way to access my files.

I mean, If I would like to see if a file exist (or read it) should I do an http request to http://mybucket.s3.amaxon.com/filename or use the S3 client ?

Or even use a distribution created and configured ad-hoc for mybucket?

Does anyone know if there is a cost difference between an HTTP request with HEAD method on s3 or cloudfront or S3 client?

I think HTTP call should be cheaper than S3 client request, but on the other hand, I cannot use authentication. And, I suppose, the Cloudfront distribution should not enable any kind of cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the `S3 client` but the most efficient way to check to see if a file exists in S3 or not is to attempt a HEAD request on the resource.  There really isn't any other way so I'm sure that under the covers that's exactly what your `S3 client` is doing, too.